# Run script with path based on environment variable

Tags: powershell, syntax, environment-variables

I have environment variable `ARTEMIS_HOME` set to `c:\artemis`.

```
PS C:\artemis_brokers> $env:ARTEMIS_HOME
C:\artemis
```

Under this directory I have a folder called bin that contains an `artemis.cmd` script. How can I run this script from anywhere in my PowerShell using the system variable?

I have tried the following with no success:

```
PS C:\artemis_brokers> $env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis
At line:1 char:19
+ $env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis
+                   ~
You must provide a value expression following the '/' operator.
At line:1 char:19
+ $env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'bin/artemis' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

```
PS C:\artemis_brokers> ./$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis
./$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis : The term './$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis'
is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ./$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (./$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

```
PS C:\artemis_brokers> ./$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis.cmd
./$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis.cmd : The term './$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/
artemis.cmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ./$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis.cmd
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (./$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis.cmd:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

```
PS C:\artemis_brokers> ./"$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis.cmd"
./$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis.cmd : The term './$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/
artemis.cmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ./"$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis.cmd"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (./$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis.cmd:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

```
PS C:\artemis_brokers> .\$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis
.\$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis : The term '.\$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis'
is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

```
PS C:\artemis_brokers> .\$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis.cmd
.\$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis.cmd : The term '.\$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/
artemis.cmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis.cmd
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis.cmd:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

```
PS C:\artemis_brokers> .\"$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis.cmd"
.\$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis.cmd : The term '.\$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/
artemis.cmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\"$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis.cmd"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis.cmd:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: just do `cmd.exe /c "$env:ARTEMIS_HOME\bin\artemis.cmd"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to expand the variable and concatenate the rest of the path into a string before you try to execute. To execute the resulting string, use `&`, [the call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#call-operator-):

```
& "$env:ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/artemis.cmd"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
& $env:ARTEMIS_HOME\bin\artemis.cmd
```